# Statically detect type mismatches in foreach statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, resharper

I have a large C# code base in which I'm trying to refactor and clean up someone else's tangled code.  I recently stumbled on a chunk like this:

```
List<Bar> bars = ... ;

...

foreach (Foo foo in bars) { ... }

...

public class Bar
{
    ...

    public static explicit operator Foo() { ... }
}
```

This type mismatch is a problem.  And, as you might expect, the code *doesn't* actually work:  It's a bug that's been hiding in plain sight for a long time.

However, the code is *legal*.  Neither Visual Studio 2013 nor ReSharper 2016 complain about this fairly obvious bug:  I had to wait until a runtime exception to discover that the code is broken.  I'd rather find out a lot earlier.

I've poked around both Visual Studio and the ReSharper options trying to find a way to make my tools detect these kinds of type mismatches:  ReSharper's "Code Patterns" is the closest I can get, and while it can recognize the syntax pattern at fault, it doesn't support deep enough type analysis to detect the bug.

So does anyone know of a way to make ReSharper statically detect `foreach` type mismatches?  Or, alternatively, does anyone know of a tool that can?

**Update:**  I omitted originally that there is an `explicit` custom casting operator from `Bar` to `Foo` — that's `explicit`, mind you, not `implicit`.  The existence of that cast operator seems to wreak havoc on the tools' ability to detect this issue.  I've updated the code in question to show the behavior.

Comment: What version of R# are you using?

Comment: ReShaper 2016.1.2, released in May 2016, to be specific.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see the update. I was about to tell you I couldn't reproduce the issue as Resharper is effectively giving me compile-time error, but if there is an explicit conversion defined, then the only way I see is to iterate filtering first using for example  list.OfType<Foo>().

Comment: Karel, this is about static code analysis, not about runtime type conversion: I have a multi-million-line code base that has a unknown number of these bugs, and I need a tool to help find all of them.

Comment: Could you update your code with the explicit cast? Just so we don't miss anything.

Comment: Also, does Foo inherit Bar?

Comment: There's no inheritance involved.  I did some more research, and found the actual answer, which I posted to this question myself.  It's weirder than you think.

Comment: Was just wondering if you could modify the code in some way to make it show up in the compiler. Can't reproduce when Foo doesn't inherit Bar
It gives me a compiler error.

Comment: You need to add a `public static explicit operator Foo()` in class `Bar` in order to reproduce it.  The key is that `explicit` operator, as I described in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, heck, so there's a solid answer, courtesy of Eric Lippert's blog.

Apparently `foreach` inserts a call to the `explicit` cast operator if there is one.

ReSharper is right to allow this, as is Visual Studio.  Sort of.  (Personally, I still think ReSharper should warn on it, even if it is legal.)

A couple of good quotes from Mr. Lippert, explaining it:

> The answer is: the foreach loop semantics were designed before generics were added to the language ... In a world with generics, where the vast majority of sequences enumerated are now statically typed, this is a misfeature. But it would be a large breaking change to remove it, so we’re stuck with it.
>
> ...
>
> You might wonder why the C# compiler does not produce a warning in modern code, where generics are being used. When I was on the C# compiler team I implemented such a warning and tried it on the corpus of C# code within Microsoft. The number of warnings produced in correct code (where someone had a sequence of Animal but knew via other means that they were all Giraffe) was large. Warnings which fire too often in correct code are bad warnings, so we opted out of adding the feature.

(The entire blog posting can be found here, and is as enlightening as it is disappointing.  https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/ )